# polymer build single element `lit-element`

Tags: javascript, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I start building sample element with polymer. When i run command polymer serve it works fine in all browser (ie also). When i want to run polymer build to build only element folder build is empty. How can i Build element to be usable in vanilla javascript ? Expected result is build index just like in sevre but ready compressed  to be used only in html. Example: index.html (comiled code from demo/index.html)

```
<head> ...scripts need to run and polyfis (webcomponents)</head>
<body>
code from demo/index.html
</body>
```

Comment: How do you build your element? with `polymer build` command?

Comment: yes. I also used https://github.com/PolymerLabs/lit-element-build-rollup and ending up code works in chrome (i no need compilation for it) but not works in ie11.

Comment: I just was offer to try the same with buil for `prpl-server` with `npm run build` ...as describbed here https://pwa-starter-kit.polymer-project.org/building-and-deploying#prpl-server-recommended

Comment: Test but that is for app like hot single element. I gues when you cur all note need stuff It willa worki.